# Plagiarism policy - how much of an answer can be copied to another answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, plagiarism

I've recently had a moderator flag declined for what I believe to be a plagiarized answer. Now I'm in doubt of what actually constitutes plagiarism.

Please compare these answers: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30362106/4) [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30362646/1)

The second answer was posted 28 minutes later and the wording has been slightly modified, but it says exactly the same thing.

For instance, answer #1 says:

> That's expected behavior of `vertical-align: baseline` (default).
>   [...] resulting in the effect you see.

And #2:

> That is expected behaviour. The `vertical-align` property by default is set to `baseline` which leads to the result.

The solution and code sample in the second answer is exactly the same as the first answer as well (with a slight whitespace difference). Note that, for those with not much CSS expertise, there is actually a dozen of ways to approach and solve this issue, which makes it rather odd for an "original" answer posted half hour after another answer to use the exactly same solution.

The only original and possibly useful part in the second answer is an outbound link, which I believe to not warrant a new answer — it should be a suggested edit or comment in the original answer.

I believe Stack Overflow would incentive improving existing content (Wiki style) rather than creating unnecessary duplication.

And in the case this is not considered plagiarism, seeing as the contents of both answers are licensed under the [CC by-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license, an adaptive work such as the second answer should at the very least provide attribution to the first answer, doesn't it?

Or, am I seeing this in the wrong light?

Comment: Its a bit suspicious to me, yes, especially with the larger time delta.

Comment: It looks like the same content, but worded entirely differently to me.  I'd say that's a pretty strong indication that the answer *didn't* copy the solution from the other.

Comment: @Servy the words themselves may be different, but it is rather odd that both answers start exactly the same way ("That's expected behavior") and follow the same structure with the same code sample. I believe in coincidences, but my gut feeling gets this one as a rewrite/adaptive work.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté But the burden of proof is on the accuser to demonstrate the plagiarism, not on him to demonstrate that he came up with the solution independently.  Personally I think it's at least pleasurable for him to have written such a solution on his own, and that there isn't compelling evidence that he stole it.

Comment: @Servy thanks, I might as well use your statements the next time I feel like plagiarizing a thesis. In all seriousness though, whether a solution has been independently developed or not, does not make answer duplication any less bad. If a very similar answer has already been posted, why not improve it instead of duplicating most of the content?

Comment: Trivial answers are often similar :/

Comment: @Will true, you have a point there. That's one of the main reasons I've started this discussion thread.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, an answer that duplicates content of another answer without adding value is typically not a *useful* answer, unless it presents that information better I guess.  That doesn't make it plagiarism, just not useful.  Feel free to vote accordingly.  As for you going off an plagarizing content because you think you won't get caught, well, that shouldn't be news.  If you can do something wrong without getting caught, you won't get punished for doing something wrong.  It's an unfortunate reality of life.

Comment: @Servy Makes sense. Sticking back to the main topic, your instance is that answers should not be flagged for plagiarism as long as they present content in a slightly different way?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I didn't say that, I said that there should be considerable evidence that the content is in fact plagiarized, and that it's not reasonable for the user to have created the content on their own.  That's not the case here, it's entirely plausible that the user didn't copy the content.

Comment: @Servy that's reasonable. Putting the question on a different light -- leaving plagiarism/original authorship aside, how about content duplication? You say the wording is completely different, hence it is not duplicated content, correct? I see it mostly as a slightly more descriptive wording version with a link added, which would be best fit as a suggested edit. I guess that's where it becomes too opinion-based and our thoughts diverge.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté If you feel that the answer isn't useful, because it's not adding any value, then feel free to downvote it, as I've already said.  Adding no useful content (because other answers contained all of the information in the posted answer with as good or better presentation) is an entirely valid justification for a post not being useful.

Comment: @Servy I'm not saying it is completely useless, otherwise I would have downvoted it already. I believe it would be best fit as an edit that improves existing content, though.

Comment: So I come to meta to ask a serious question in order to improve my rules understanding, link to revisions in order to minimize the meta effect, and yet some people are not happy to downvote this discussion but also go to the heights of voting in the main site out of nonsensical spite instead of merit. Dear anonymous user, just remember that when people complain about Stack Overflow being unwelcoming and hostile, you are at fault.

Comment: Fabrício, you've received a single downvote on your SO profile. That is _hardly_ anything to complain about, and for all you know is from someone who found your answer without having ever visited Meta and did not find it useful. It's also on a very recent answer of yours, which makes that even more plausible. Don't stress over one downvote. (Ditto for the _single_ downvote this post has received.)

Comment: @Kendra I don't particularly care about my reputation (which is a mere byproduct of my contributions), nor the downvotes specifically. What I do stress over is the peculiar behavior of anonymously downvoting without any apparent reason and without providing any constructive feedback (e.g. commenting or suggesting edits). But this is a completely different topic, of course. `:)` Although the voting process is anonymous, I just saw the timeframe to be quite suspicious and could only assume the downvoter to be the same as I don't see another reason to downvote a correct answer. But there is -

Comment: - no reason to stress over, anyway. On the upside, my reputation is finally round again. `=]`

Comment: The most aggravating cases are when the answer is plagiarized almost word for word, complete with code formatting, so as to be lifted to the top of the list.

Comment: I have had this a few time with trivial answers; you start typing it in, and then the phones goes, after you finished the call you finish typing and post

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Give the person the benefit of the doubt here.

If the question is extremely easy (as in, there's generally one conventional approach to it), the answers are going to read very similarly.

I do find it eerie that the fiddles you both link to are the **exact same code**, however.  But that's only one part of the answer; the way you both elaborate on it is divergent enough to distinguish between the two.  Maybe the other person's a slow typer?

If it were more blatant they would have copied a lot more from you.  This sort of embellishment doesn't seem to rise to the occasion of plagiarism.

Comment: "I do find it eerie that the fiddles you both link to are the exact same code, however." They are both forked from the same fiddle in the question. Nothing suspicious there.

Comment: slower typer? how much slower should you be to type 2 paragraphs in 30 minutes?

Comment: Ever hear of "hunt and peck"?  It's still a thing even amongst the computer-savvy.

Comment: @Makoto No (I read it), but I heard about math. Having an answer with 500 characters written almost an hour later makes a speed in 10 chars/minute. I agree that it is possible to come up with hundreds of explanations like he fall asleep almost finishing his answer, woke up an hour later and pressed submit, but the most obvious is that a person just wanted to get few points of rep. P.S. you clearly see when new answers are coming via updates.

Comment: @SalvadorDali A lot of folks browse Stack Overflow by opening up several tabs and then going through them.  Perhaps the user opened the question and then answered it?  Often times the notifications for other answers does not work.

Comment: Ok, well that's fine, but the other answers show up once you post yours.  Someone beat you to the punch by 28 minutes and you don't think its a little tacky to keep your answer there?

Comment: @cimmanon:  It's not a "first-person-wins" sort of thing.  If there are two answers which can dutifully stand on their own merits, then that's perfectly acceptable - even if they answer the question in a similar way.

Comment: Perhaps a small amendment: I think it is ok to copy small pieces of code *given you make a reference to the answer where you copied them from*. It can be useful to shortcut code a bit such that one can provide a full working example instead of a *collage.*

Comment: @CommuSoft: If the code was complex and intricate I could see that; otherwise it's a waste of time.  You can't prove that a small, trivial snippet of code came from exclusively one person.

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/a/21871253/3519951 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18332000/3519951, should that be flagged? I hesitate now to flag and edit plagiarism since one of my edits to add in a missing license and author reference on a whole copied class was refused by reviewers as non-relevant.

Answer (score 28):

I declined your flag. We only handle plagiarism cases that are clear attempts to copy content from another source rather than simply original work that demonstrates the same idea(s).

There was no evidence of the former here. The user just happened to post a very similar answer, using their own words. I say this not only as a moderator, but also as someone with experience in the subject matter.

While we'd like to have as little content duplication as possible, we don't necessarily prefer pure wiki editing over multiple answers sorted by votes (not in every situation anyway); otherwise, we would have defaulted all answers to community wiki and abolished rep-based voting entirely. Furthermore, if someone feels that they have their own way of expressing an idea, they would want to post their own answer rather than try to put their words in someone else's mouth (which I'm sure the other user wouldn't appreciate either, otherwise they would have posted their answer as a wiki). This is why we allow multiple answers, even if they're based on similar ideas.

The only exception to this is low-effort answers to old or popular questions that have been answered several times over. Things like

> *[the same one or two lines of code from a dozen other answers to the same question]*
>
> write like this u will get it

as well as *that, several times over*. That is the sort of content duplication we don't want, because those answers make no attempt to stand out whatsoever and serve only to clutter up the question.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation, your answer makes perfect sense. I agree that the same solution expressed in different ways will ultimately help the readers, which is Stack Overflow's goal. I just saw both posts' contents to be way too alike, but I guess I was too quick to judge. Your answer and Makoto's really cleared it up for me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're really asking two things here:

1. Is this plagiarism? [Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294967/908494) and [BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294976/908494) answered that.
2. Even if it isn't plagiarism, isn't it still making the site worse, and shouldn't there be same way to deal with it?

For #2, the question is whether it really is making the site worse. I'll assume that you're right that there is no useful information to be gained by having the second answer. It doesn't explain anything better, have any extra information, etc.

But is it getting in the way of finding other information?

You say "for those with not much CSS expertise, there is actually a dozen of ways to approach and solve this issue". And I've definitely seen questions where there are three very good answers with very different approaches, but then effective duplicates of the most obvious one push the alternatives down the page. That's a problem, and it sounds like it *could* happen here. (Although it hasn't happened here yet, and it's quite possible it never will.)

You could try to encourage the person who wrote the duplicate answer to delete it, with a polite comment explaining that it doesn't add anything and might get in the way of alternative answers, and/or (if you think it's appropriate) a downvote.

But beyond that, I don't think there is anything you can do that isn't an abuse of flags, or in some other way worse than the problem you're trying to solve.