# What are the criteria for plagiarism?

Tags: support, plagiarism

Maybe the answer is subjective, unless the only criterion is a copy-paste job, in which case it's objective but narrow.

But I recently had a flag declined so I'm looking for guidance. Note these aren't FGITW answers, the 2 answers in question came 3 days after the question was posted.

**Solution 1**

```
order = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(('First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'))}

sorter = sorted(d['Attributes'].items(), key=lambda x: order[x[0]])

L = [dict(enumerate({k: v} for k, v in sorter))]
```

**Solution 2**

```
order = {value: key for key, value in enumerate(('First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'))}

sorted_form = sorted(dict_value['Attributes'].items(), key=lambda d: order[d[0]])

final_list = [dict(enumerate({key: value} for key, value in sorted_form))]
```

I've omitted several lines of explanation preceding the code, but the Edit history for Solution 2 clearly shows these lines being added *after* Solution 1 was posted.

Solution 2 was an edit to a post 3.5 hours after the solution was initially posted and 2.5 hours after Solution 1 was posted (with no edits).

I was just looking for a roll-back. I thought this one was pretty obvious, but maybe it wasn't. Should I bother flagging these?

Comment: What type of flag did you use? Custom mod flag?

Comment: @BSMP, "In need of moderator attention" and I explained in a few words: `Potential plagiarism. This answer has code copied directly from my own answer. Just 2 hours later.`

Comment: The rest of the answer that you omitted could be precisely what makes the question fit the plagiarism flag or not. If beyond these three lines the answers are different enough, I wouldn't consider it a plagiarism case.

Comment: I think the answer from BoltClock [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294948/plagiarism-policy-how-much-of-an-answer-can-be-copied-to-another-answer?rq=1) applies.